# C# WPF ObservableCollection does not update Grid

Tags: wpf, grid, observablecollection, auto-update

My implementation of an ObservableCollection does not update my Grid and I don't know why:

The first XAML-Window 'UserControlStaff.xaml' displays the Grid where the user data can be seen. The second XAML-Window allows to add users and is called 'CreateUser.xaml'.
The code behind the XAML-Windows is attached to this post as well.

My Code goes as follows:

**[XAML] UserControlStaff.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.UserControlStaff"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="786">

    <StackPanel x:Name="spStaff" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="Visible">
        <Button Background="Azure" Click="btnCreateUser_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="786" Height="40">
            <Bold>Mitarbeiter hinzufügen</Bold></Button>
        <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="504">
            <DataGrid Background="#DBDB72" ItemsSource="{Binding UserDataObject}" CanUserAddRows="false" Width="786" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

**[Code] UserControlStaff.xaml.cs**

```
namespace MyApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für UserControlStaff.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControlStaff : UserControl
    {
        ObservableCollection<User> mUserDataObject = new ObservableCollection<User>();

        public ObservableCollection<User> UserDataObject
        {
            get
            {
                return mUserDataObject;
            }
        }

        public UserControlStaff()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            try
            {
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyApp.Properties.Settings.ConString"].ConnectionString;
                string queryString = string.Empty;

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    queryString = "SELECT ID, username AS Username, Password AS Passwort, (SELECT role FROM Roles WHERE ID = t1.role) AS Rolle FROM Users t1 ORDER BY ID";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Users");
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        int pID = 0;
                        string pUsername = "";
                        string pPassword = "";
                        string pRole = "";

                        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            if (col.ToString().Trim() == "ID")
                            {
                                pID = int.Parse(row[col].ToString());
                            }
                            else if (col.ToString().Trim() == "Username")
                            {
                                pUsername = row[col].ToString();
                            }
                            else if (col.ToString().Trim() == "Passwort")
                            {
                                pPassword = row[col].ToString();
                            }
                            else if (col.ToString().Trim() == "Rolle")
                            {
                                pRole = row[col].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                        // Show Users DB table in MainWindow
                        mUserDataObject.Add(new User { ID = pID, Username = pUsername, Password = pPassword, Role = pRole });
                    }

                    // Show Users DB table in MainWindow
                    //XAML Grid: Name="gridUsers"
                    //CS Code: gridUsers.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
                }
            }
            catch {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private void btnCreateUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CreateUser popup = new CreateUser();
            popup.Show();
        }

        private void UpdateUserData()
        {
            // implement
        }

        private void DeleteUserData()
        {
            // implement
        }
    }
}
```

**[XAML] CreateUser.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.CreateUser"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Mitarbeiter hinzufügen" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="30"/>
        <Label Content="Passwort" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="30"/>
        <Label Content="Rolle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="30"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="150,44,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="TextBoxUsername" Text="{Binding Path=Username}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="150,88,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="TextBoxPassword" Text="{Binding Path=Password}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180"/>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="150,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
        <Button Click="btnSaveUserData_Click" Content="Speichern" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="217,219,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="75"/>
        <Button Click="btnCloseWindow_Click" Content="Abbrechen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="297,219,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**[Code] CreateUser.xaml.cs**

```
namespace MyApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für CreateUser.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CreateUser : Window
    {
        User userObject;

        public CreateUser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.userObject = new User();
        }

        private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // ToDO: Rollenzuweisung automatisieren aus Datenbanktabelle MyApp.Roles
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            data.Add("Chef");
            data.Add("Restaurantmitarbeiter");
            data.Add("Fahrer");

            // ... Get the ComboBox reference.
            var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

            // ... Assign the ItemsSource to the List.
            comboBox.ItemsSource = data;

            // ... Make the second item selected.
            comboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }

        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // ... Get the ComboBox.
            var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

            // ... Set SelectedItem as Window Title.
            string value = comboBox.SelectedItem as string;
            //this.Title = "Selected: " + value;

            this.userObject.Role = value;
        }

        private void btnSaveUserData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.userObject.Username = TextBoxUsername.Text;
                this.userObject.Password = TextBoxPassword.Text;

                int UserRole;

                // ToDO: Rollenzuweisung automatisieren aus Datenbanktabelle MyApp.Roles
                if (this.userObject.Role == "Chef")
                {
                    UserRole = 1;
                }
                else if (this.userObject.Role == "Restaurantmitarbeiter")
                {
                    UserRole = 2;
                }
                else if (this.userObject.Role == "Fahrer")
                {
                    UserRole = 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    UserRole = 2; // Default UserRole is "Restaurantmitarbeiter"
                }


                if (this.userObject.Username.Trim() != "" && this.userObject.Password.Trim() != "")
                {
                    CreateUserData(this.userObject.Username, this.userObject.Password, UserRole);
                    // ToDO: Update DataGrid in UserControlStaff
                    this.Close();

                    MessageBox.Show("Mitarbeiter hinzugefügt!");
                } else {
                    MessageBox.Show("Bitte Username und Passwort eingeben.");
                }
            }
            catch { throw; }
        }

        private void CreateUserData(string pUsername, string pPassword, int pRole)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyApp.Properties.Settings.ConString"].ConnectionString;
            string queryString = "INSERT INTO Users (ID, username, password, role) VALUES ((SELECT TOP 1 ID+1 FROM Users ORDER BY ID DESC), '" + pUsername + "', '" + pPassword + "', '" + pRole + "')";

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Users");
            sda.Fill(dt);

            string UserRole;
            if (pRole == 1)
            {
                UserRole = "Chef";
            }
            else if (pRole == 2)
            {
                UserRole = "Restaurantmitarbeiter";
            }
            else if (pRole == 3)
            {
                UserRole = "Fahrer";
            }
            else
            {
                UserRole = "Restaurantmitarbeiter"; // Default UserRole is "Restaurantmitarbeiter"
            }

            // Add to Observable Collection
            // ToDO
            // mUserDataObject.Add(new User { ID = pID, Username = pUsername, Password = pPassword, Role = pRole });
        }

        private void btnCloseWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post UserControlStaff.xaml code?

Comment: Is attached beneath. Please see "UserControlStaff.xaml.cs"

Comment: under UserControlStaff.xaml you've copied the cs code ... atleast that's what I see.

Comment: UserControlStaff.xaml code is UserControlStaff.xaml.cs isn't it?

Comment: I see UserControlStaff.xaml.cs 2 times... But no UserControlStaff.xaml

Comment: But actually your question is "why the Grid is not updated?" or "How to update the ObservableCollection from another window?" Because your code that should update the collection is commented.

Comment: LOL. My fault. Thought I copied the right stuff from my clipboard. Reading helps :) Thank you for your information.

Comment: My question is: Why does the Grid not update when I create a new user?

Comment: How can I tell the ObservableCollection the update from the creating window? I mean the ObservableCollection is defined in UserControlStaff.xaml.cs and the user itself is created in CreateUser.xaml.cs. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: The easiest way is to add the collection as a parameter of CreateUser window and add the user where you marked //ToDo.
A more cleaner solution is probably to reload users from the database in UserControlStaff.xaml.cs after CreateUser window closes. I mean cleaner as someone else has potentially updated the data base meanwhile.

Comment: The first (easiest) solution works fine for me. Thank you very much. Additionally, how can I update and delete those rows now in the Grid?

Comment: Use the SelectedItem property of the DataGrid to access the selected User and then delete it from the collection and the database. But it's another question ...

Comment: I'm really happy to got this fast solution! If necessary I will open up a next post.